# HTML/CSS Changing a page's background-image through event

Tags: html, css, windows

I'm playing around with Active Desktop on an old WinXP machine.
I have my background set up with an iframe and links pointing it to certain folders to make it easier/faster to navigate. I'd like a link to change the background-image of the iframe without having to resort to make a new page everytime I find a new image I want as a background-image. While I have no clue how, I'm fairly sure it's something CSS ought be able to handle.
The catch is that Active Desktop refuses to run Javascript.

So is it possible to change the background image of a page by clicking a link without using javascript?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

via CSS you could use the pseudo :hover
However, that would only last for as long as you hover. If I understand you correct, you want a permanent change of image without scripting, or just without JS? You could try WSH. Perhaps there is some useful function in there, or maybe VB?

Comment: No dice on WSH, HTA or VB. I can use .bat files though, but that might only overcomplicate things.